# Lyrics API returns indented text, but how do I fix it for html?

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, indentation

[image]

I use this API to grab lyrics: http://www.chartlyrics.com/api.aspx

Unfortunately text is not html indented. How do I parse it so that in web browser I have correct spacing / indentation?

```
if ($_GET['get_lyrics'] == 1 AND $_GET['song_name'] AND $_GET['song_author']) {
    //via http://api.chartlyrics.com/
    $url = "http://api.chartlyrics.com/apiv1.asmx/SearchLyricDirect?artist=".$_GET['song_author']."&song=".$_GET['song_name'];
    $url = str_replace(" ", '%20', $url);

    //
    $header = array();
    $header[] = 'Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5';
    $header[] = 'Cache-Control: max-age=0';
    $header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    $header[] = 'Keep-Alive: 300';
    $header[] = 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7';
    $header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5';
    $header[] = 'Pragma: ';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    //
    if ($result) {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
        print_r(json_encode($xml->Lyric));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use [php.net/nl2br](http://www.php.net/nl2br) to get the new lines. You need anything else?

Comment: @Reeno I tried that, it returned 1 letter. I think I've problem with php.

Comment: You can also use pre html element

Comment: Can you share a link to your website / page with the output? It can be a `css` issue.

Comment: @OfirBaruch http://mac.idev.ge:800/jmobile-radio/

Comment: Replace `$url = str_replace(" ", '%20', $url);` with `$url = urlencode($url);`, this also handles other chars than whitespace.

Comment: I don't see the nl2br there. Try replacing `print_r(json_encode($xml->Lyric));` with `echo nl2br(json_encode($xml->Lyric));`

Comment: I don't see indents at all :O What is your definition for indent?

Comment: @Reeno I tried it nl2br($xml->Lyric) wrong place to use it.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I meant spaces or \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what are you trying to do, but try `nl2br($text)` to add html line endings and then use CSS to style it the way you want, other option is to put it in `<pre></pre>` tags and style the element.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pre instead of a div.

Or parse the text :

- Use a regex to get the different paragraphs and use p around them.
- Or just replace "\n" in your text with br
- use nl2br